How to add UAE Pass as identity provider to Azure AD B2C
UAE Pass does not provide a .../.well-known/openid-configuration (Metadata url) endpoint. To register a custom idp in Azure AD B2C it requires the Metadata url.
Is there a way to setup a custom idp by entering the required endpoints manually. UAE Pass only provides the following endpoints:

.../authorize
.../token
.../userinfo
.../logout

I have looked to see if I could provide the endpoints in the manifest file or in a custom flow, but I cannot see a way to do it.
I will appreciate any help.

From what I can tell, UAE Pass only implements the OAuth 2.0 specification and not OpenID Connect (OIDC), which is an extension of OAuth.
With Azure AD B2C User Flows (the out-of-box, click and create experience), you are only able to add a custom OIDC provider.
With Custom Policies (XML files in the Identity Experience Framework blade), you can implement an OAuth 2.0 provider.

Please do not forget to "Accept the answer” and “up-vote” wherever the information provided helps you, this can be beneficial to other community members.
